# Quantum mechanics successive measurements (incompatible observables)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, terminology

I started a "principles of quantum mechanics" course this year, and already have a problem with successive measurements (using Dirac notation). The question is about incompatible observables A and B. An experiment is performed to measure observable A, then observable B, and then A again, where the eigenvalues A1 and A2 can then be retrieved each with their own probability.

To find the probability of getting the value of observable A to be A1 in the end, I literally draw a probability tree, and count and sum the probabilities along the required branch. However, I would like to know how this is done using Dirac's notation (for more complex successive measurements, for example).

Here is the exercise:

The observables A and B are represented by operators $ \hat A $ and $ \hat B $ with eigenfunctions { u$_i$(x) } and { v$_i$(x) } respectively, such that

v$_1$(x) = { $\sqrt 3 u_1(x) + u_2(x)$ } / 2

v$_2$(x) = { $u_1(x) − \sqrt 3 u_2(x)$ } / 2

A certain system is subjected to three successive measurements:

(i) a measurement of A

(ii) a measurement of B

(iii) another measurement of A

Show that if measurement (i) yields the value A1 there is a probability of 5/8
that (iii) will yield A1 and a probability of 3/8 that it will yield A2.

Comment: _but have no idea how to use LaTeX._ To be straight with you, it's not going to help you get an answer saying that, MathJax is just a markup notation, it's not complicated at all  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. The best of luck with it anyway

Comment: Thanks for that, I was looking for the link. Added the exact question/exercise

Answer (score 1):

If the first measurement yields the value $A_1$ with certainty, this means the initial state has collapsed into $u_1$ after the first observation. In particular one has, inverting the above back:
$$
|u_1\rangle =\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|v_1\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|v_2\rangle.
$$
Now a measurement of the observable $B$ must be performed and then one more measurement of $A$. The probability of getting again $A_1$ is, by Bayes' theorem
$$
P(A_1 | B) = P(v_1)P(A_1|v_1) + P(v_2)P(A_1|v_2).
$$
Computing each contribution starting from the components coefficients that you have in $|u_1\rangle$ we find
$$
P(A_1 | B) = {\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}^2\cdot{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}^2 + {\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^2\cdot {\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^2 = \frac{5}{8}.
$$